# Order By com List<>

Tags: c#, linq, lista, order-by, order

É possível efetuar um `OrderBy` em um `List<>` definindo o valor para comparação?

Exemplo:

```
mRel.OrderBy(s => s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Novo).ToList()
```

Meu Código:

```
List<MotivosModel.MotivosRel> mRel = CarregarMotivosRelacionados(null);

mRel = mRel.OrderBy(s => s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Novo)
           .ThenBy(s => s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Falha).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Usando o método [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) do Linq.

Você só precisa atentar que a ordenação **`s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Novo`** vai colocar os elementos que atendem esta condição **pro final**.

Isso porque a ordenação é feita com base no resultado da expressão, ou seja, `true` (1) e `false` (0). Logo, tudo o que não atender a condição será colocado a frente (isso, se estiver usando a ordenação ascendente, obviamente).

Então, é só inverter as expressões que sua lista ficará ordenada como você quer

```
mRel = mRel.OrderBy(s => s.Status != EnumModel.StatusGeral.Novo)
            .ThenBy(s => s.Status != EnumModel.StatusGeral.Falha)
            .ToList();
```

Obviamente também é possível só trocando os métodos por `OrderByDescending` e `ThenByDescending`.

Veja um exemplo ([é possível vê-lo funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vCz9kf)). Ele ordena colocando primeiro quem tem o status como `Novo` e depois como `Falha`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lista = new[] { new Coisa { Nome = "Novo Teste", Status = StatusGeral.Novo}, 
                            new Coisa { Nome = "Falha Teste", Status = StatusGeral.Falha}, 
                            new Coisa { Nome = "Novo Teste 2", Status = StatusGeral.Novo},
                            new Coisa { Nome = "Outro Teste", Status = StatusGeral.Outro} };

        lista = lista.OrderBy(s => s.Status != StatusGeral.Novo)
                     .ThenBy(s => s.Status != StatusGeral.Falha)
                     .ToArray();

        foreach(var p in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Nome);
        }           
    }
}

public class Coisa
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public StatusGeral Status { get; set; }
}

public enum StatusGeral
{
    Novo,
    Falha,
    Outro
}
```

Comment: Assim vai chegar nos 100k rapidinho :)

Comment: Assim como? @Ismael

Comment: Pelas ótimas rápidas repostas!

Comment: Ah, obrigado =) @Ismael

Comment: Perfeito amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. a ordenação eu fiz usando o OrderByDescending.    mRel = mRel.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Novo).
                            ThenByDescending(s => s.Status == EnumModel.StatusGeral.Falha).ToList();

Comment: Exato. O resultado final é o mesmo. Bom poder ajudar. =D